# Force div to fill browser width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small js file that adds a bar to the top of the page. This file can be included on all kinds of site designs. Any pages that have body margin/padding set to 0, the bar displays fine. However, if the page has a left or right padding, the bar will not stretch full width.

Problem is I don't want to manipulate the page body style, as the design may have a reason for it. So my question is:

How can I force the div to fill the width of the browser without manipulating the body padding/margin?

I've searched for a while now and the answers all say to set the body padding/margin.

Thank you

EDIT:

I can't rely on jquery for this. Currently using plain javascript to add the html for the bar. doc = dochtml+'  html string.... '+dochtml...

EDIT 2:

I am writing all the style and HTML in. Not linking to any external files. Like a CSS reset, that would create issues for the rest of the elements. This bar is something people will include into their sites, I can't mess with their design.

Answer (score 3):

Just after the opening `<body>` tag you'll need to add a `<div>` tag. The div's style should be something like

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0;
    width:100%
    height: 20px;
}
```

The div should always be the width of the browser. If you need to add some padding to it, you'll need to add another div inside the containing one otherwise the padding will make the width more than 100%. You'll also need to add a margin to the body to make sure the floating div doesn't overlap the bodies content. I hope that makes sense!

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/rZKrL/show/)

Comment: How about wrapping everything inside the body inside another div and add the margin to that?

Comment: Creative idea :) Trying to think how to go about it, or if any cons... Thank you